# Selenium WebDriver with Java - how to add "else" condition

Tags: java, selenium

I have code:

```
public void setList(By localizator, String v_value {
        Select some_list = new Select(driver.findElement(localizator));
        for(WebElement position_list : some_list.getOptions()) {
            if(position_list.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(v_value)) {
                some_list.selectByVisibleText(position_list.getText());
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

How can I add condition: if selenium doesn't find position_list.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(v_value) then system throw new RuntimeExpression?

Answer (score 0):

Use `iterator` instead of `foreach`, it provides a `hasNext()` method with which you can check if you are currently dealing with the last element of your list.

```
Iterator<WebElement> iterator = some_list.getOptions().iterator();
```

and then instead of your foreach:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   WebElement current = iterator.next();
   if(current.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(v_value)) {
            current.selectByVisibleText(position_list.getText());
            break;
        }
   if(!iterator.hasNext()){
   throw new RuntimeException();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion from what I see in your code.

When you use `some_list.selectByVisibleText(position_list.getText());` the `selectByVisibleText(..)` method is already setup to iterate over all available options and select the one that matches the text parameter you pass in. Putting the call inside a loop checking for the option to be available is not ideal if you are looking to throw an exception.

Also, let's say you have the following code -

```
public void setList(By localizator, String v_value {
    Select some_list = new Select(driver.findElement(localizator));
    some_list.selectByVisibleText(position_list.getText());
    ....
}
```

In this case `selectByVisibleText` would throw a `NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate element with text: " + text);` in case the option is not available for selection. You should be able to catch that and throw a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple answer to your question is a try catch

```
public void setList(By localizator, String v_value {
Select some_list = new Select(driver.findElement(localizator));
for(WebElement position_list : some_list.getOptions()) {
    try{
            if(position_list.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(v_value)) {
                some_list.selectByVisibleText(position_list.getText());
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(RuntimeExpression ex)
        {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```